# Nullable data types in databinding?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, ado.net

I'm using Typed Data sets in my C# application to communicate with the database. My database supports and allows null values on many of the records. However, it seems that trying to access a nulled value through the dataset results in a Cast exception.

Is it possible to make the properties nullable (atleast the ones that can store a null value in the database)? If not why was it designed this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make the properties nullable

No, the Generator tool does not support this.

> If not why was it designed this way?

The Dataset dates back to Fx 1.1 , nullable value types to Fx 2.0

When Fx2 was released it was decided not to change the Typed Dataset framework (for cost and time reasons presumably).

The Dataset framework has not been updated since, I think there is an official statement somewhere they're in an end-of-life stage.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer - [Typed DataSet nullable support](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataset/thread/407cca6d-2364-47ca-821e-77a1cad574cf) they (MSFT) says type dataset doesn't support nullable values in dot net 4.0

Comment: Any reason given for why? A null values is a perfectly reasonable for a database record.

Comment: Legacy, fact that most serious apps dont use datasets to start with. Stuff along this line.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make the properties nullable 
>   (atleast the ones that can store a null value in the database)?

Although you cannot store nullable value types in a typed `DataSet`, you can make the data set columns accept `DBNull` values (`column.AllowDBNull = true;`) and create a pair of helper functions that will do that translation for you.

```
    public static T? DBToNullable<T>(object dbValue) where T: struct 
    {
        if (dbValue == DBNull.Value)
            return null;
        else
            return (T)dbValue;
    }

    public static object NullableToDB<T>(T? value) where T: struct
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
            return (object)(T)value;
        else
            return DBNull.Value;
    }
```

They can then be used like this:

```
    int? value = ....
    DataRow row = ....

    row["MyDataColumn"] = NullableToDB(value);

    value = DBToNullable<int>(row["MyDataColumn"]);
```

That should ease the pain somewhat.

> If not why was it designed this way?

It was probably designed this way for historical reasons that relate to the conceptual difference between a database `NULL` value (meaning: the value is unknown) and a C# `null` reference (meaning: this reference hasn’t yet been assigned). Of course, those meanings changed after nullable value types were added to C#, but by then the typed `DataSet` ship had already sailed.

Comment: Hihi, that code makes me laugh. It's good, but the value-on-value metas make it read a bit weird. And I to think "if (value.HasValue) return (object)(T)value;" should be "if (value.HasValue) return value.Value;". A method returning object certainly need not explicitly upcast the result. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create Nullable value types in .NET. You can just use Nullable generic or just put ? to make the value type nullable. I am not sure if the designer generates them automatically for a typed dataaset. Please look at 
http://xtremebytes.blogspot.com/2010/12/nullable.html for reference

Comment: It doesn't add the Nullable<T> interface to the values by default or ever as far as I can tell.

Comment: This throws a NotSupportedException: "DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>."